# SHA1 hash of every file in a directory tree

Tags: python, parsing, cryptography

I have a few important files that I would like to preserve, so I make multiple backups of them. In order to check their integrity, I decided to write a python script that would help me with this task.

It does exactly what it should, it traverses a directory tree starting from where the script is executed, calculates the hashes of the files it finds and writes them to a text file. It can also calculate the hashes again and check them against the ones that are in the text file.

```
import hashlib
import os
import sys

# Description of a hashlist element:
# hashlist[0] = (SHA1_HASH, PARTIAL_FILE_PATH)
# Partial file path is used in order to keep the script
# cross platform; every time the full file path is 
# needed, the current working directory gets added to 
# the partial file path

# parameters: filename (full path)
# reads it in 4096 bytes chunks and feeds them to the sha1 function
# returns the sha1 hash
# PS I got this code snippet from stackoverflow

def sha1(fname):
  hash_sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
  with open(fname, "rb") as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
      hash_sha1.update(chunk)
  return hash_sha1.hexdigest()

# parameters: a path, verbose flag (false if message is not needed)
# walks the directory tree generated by the os.walk method, creates 
# a hashlist
# returns the created hashlist

def create_hashlist_from_path(path, verbose=True):
  hashlist = []
  ignored_files = ['directoryTree_integrity_check.py', 'directory.sha1'] # add here the files you want to exclude from the integrity check
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    files.sort() # preventing unexpected results by sorting the file names first
    for name in files:
      if (name not in ignored_files):
        path_to_be_written = root
        path_to_be_written = path_to_be_written.replace(path, "")
        # removing the '/' at the beginning else os.path.join treats it as an absolute path
        # which is not what we want
        if path_to_be_written.startswith('\\'):
          path_to_be_written = path_to_be_written[1:]
        hashlist.append(((sha1(os.path.join(root, name)), os.path.join(path_to_be_written, name)))) # appends a new sha1 digest - file path tuple to the list
        if verbose == True:
          print(name + " Done")
  return hashlist

# parameters: a hashlist
# writes the sha1 hash of the file and the partial file path itself to file, in this order  
# and one per line
# function is void

def write_hashlist_to_file(hashlist):
  with open('directory.sha1', 'w+') as f:
    for couple in hashlist:
      f.write(couple[0] + ' ' + couple[1] + '\n')
  return

# parameters: none
# reads file line by line, strips the trailing newline from it 
# splicing is used to separate sha1 hash from partial file path
# returns the parsed hashlist

def parse_hashlist_file():
  hashlist = []
  with open('directory.sha1', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
      line = line.strip()
      sha1_hash = line[:40]
      file_path = line[41:]
      hashlist.append((sha1_hash, file_path))
  hashlist = add_cwd_to_hashlist(hashlist)
  return hashlist

# parameters: a hashlist
# adds the cwd to the partial file path 
# returns the fixed hashlist

def add_cwd_to_hashlist(hashlist):
  new_hashlist = []
  for couple in hashlist:
    new_hashlist.append((couple[0], (os.path.join(cwd, couple[1]))))
  return new_hashlist

def create_and_write_hashlist_to_file():
  print("Calculating hashes...")
  hashlist = create_hashlist_from_path(cwd)
  print("Writing hashes to file...")
  write_hashlist_to_file(hashlist)
  print("Done")
  return

def print_menu():
  print("1. Calculate and write SHA1 hashes to file")
  print("2. Calculate SHA1 hashes and check them against file")
  print("3. Exit")


if __name__ == '__main__':

  cwd = os.getcwd()
  menu_choice = 0
  print_menu()

  while menu_choice != 3:
    print("Type in your choice:")

    # check if the menu_choice is different from the 3 allowed
    while True:
      try:
        menu_choice = int(input('>'))
      except ValueError:
        pass
      if (menu_choice > 0 or menu_choice < 4):
        break

    if menu_choice == 1:
      # check if 'directory.sha1' exists first
      if os.path.isfile('directory.sha1'):
        print("SHA1 hashes file exists already")
        print("Do you want to overwrite it? y/n")
        response = input()
        if response == 'y':
          create_and_write_hashlist_to_file()
      else:
        create_and_write_hashlist_to_file()

    elif menu_choice == 2:
      # check if 'directory.sha1' does not exist
      if not os.path.isfile('directory.sha1'):
        print("SHA1 hashes file has not been found")
        print("Do you want to create it? y/n")
        response = input()
        # basically do what menu_choice 1 does
        if response == 'y':
          create_and_write_hashlist_to_file()
      # 'directory.sha1' exist
      else:
        mismatch_number = 0
        # parse it
        parsed_hashlist = parse_hashlist_file()
        # check parsed data against what we calculate in every iteration
        print("Checking...")
        for couple in parsed_hashlist:
          try:
            if couple[0] != sha1(couple[1]):
              # print("MISMATCH " + '"' + couple[1][ ( (couple[1].rfind('\\') ) + 1) : ] + '"')
              print("MISMATCH " + '"' + couple[1] + '"')
              mismatch_number += 1
          except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File" + ' " ' + couple[1] + ' " ' + "has not been found" )
            mismatch_number += 1 
        if mismatch_number == 0:
          print("All files match")

    elif menu_choice == 3:
      pass

  print("Exiting...")
  sys.exit(0)
```

I would like to know though if there is something that I could have done better/written more efficiently and if my codestyle and comments are somewhat acceptable.

Thank you in advance for the criticism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Working with paths

This is hacky:

> ```
> path_to_be_written = root
> path_to_be_written = path_to_be_written.replace(path, "")
> # removing the '/' at the beginning else os.path.join treats it as an absolute path
> # which is not what we want
> if path_to_be_written.startswith('\\'):
>   path_to_be_written = path_to_be_written[1:]
> ```

It's better to use the various functions of `os.path` for path manipulations, for example:

```
path_to_be_written = os.path.relpath(root, start=path)
```

#### Use list comprehensions

This is a natural candidate for using list comprehensions:

> ```
> new_hashlist = []
> for couple in hashlist:
>   new_hashlist.append((couple[0], (os.path.join(cwd, couple[1]))))
> return new_hashlist
> ```

Like this:

```
return [(couple[0], os.path.join(cwd, couple[1])) for couple in hashlist]
```

I also removed some redundant parentheses.

If `couple` always has two elements, then you can do even better:

```
return [(hash, os.path.join(cwd, relpath)) for hash, relpath in hashlist]
```

#### Coding style

There are several coding style issues:

- [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends to use 4 spaces for indentation. It has many other recommendations relevant to the posted code, I suggest to read it carefully and follow it.
- An empty `return` statement at the end of a function is pointless, it's better to omit it.
- Instead of `if verbose == True:` it's better to write `if verbose:`
- Instead of `path_to_be_written = root; path_to_be_written = path_to_be_written.replace(path, "")` it would be better to write `path_to_be_written = root.replace(path, "")`
- Similarly, instead of `hashlist = add_cwd_to_hashlist(hashlist); return hashlist`, this is better: `return add_cwd_to_hashlist(hashlist)`

Comment: Coming from a C background, I thought that I could use an empty return statement. Guess it's not the case. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @SirAugustin well you *can*, but if it's pointless, then you shouldn't